# Recuperar total de items desde combinaciones

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en una base de PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE combinaciones
(
   id    serial NOT NULL,
   valor character varying NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

ALTER TABLE combinaciones OWNER TO postgres;
```

A la cual le he insertado los siguientes valores:

```
INSERT INTO combinaciones (valor)
VALUES
  ('A.1;B.1;F'),
  ('A.2.1;B.1;F'),
  ('A.2.1;F'),
  ('A.3;B.1;F'),
  ('A.3;B.2;F'),
  ('A.3;C;D.1;F'),
  ('A.3;C;F'),
  ('A.3;D.1;F'),
  ('A.3;F'),
  ('B.1;B.2;F');
```

Necesito recuperar el total de item cargados en todas las combinaciones, algo asi:

```
A.1   =  1 veces
A.2.1 =  2 veces
A.3   =  6 veces
B.1   =  4 veces
B.2   =  2 veces
C     =  2 veces
D.1   =  2 veces
F     = 10 veces
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
  (
    CASE
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%A.1%'   THEN 'A.1'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%A.2.1%' THEN 'A.2.1'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%A.2.2%' THEN 'A.2.2'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%A.3%'   THEN 'A.3'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%A.4%'   THEN 'A.4'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%B.1%'   THEN 'B.1'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%B.2%'   THEN 'B.21'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%C%'     THEN 'C'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%D.1%'   THEN 'D.1'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%D.2%'   THEN 'D.2'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%D.3%'   THEN 'D.3'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%E.1%'   THEN 'E.1'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%E.2%'   THEN 'E.2'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%E.3%'   THEN 'E.3'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%F%'     THEN 'F'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%G.1%'   THEN 'G.1'
      WHEN combinacion LIKE '%G.2%'   THEN 'G.2'
    END
  ) AS item,
  SUM(total) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT
    valor        AS combinacion,
    COUNT(valor) AS total
  FROM combinaciones
  GROUP BY combinacion
  ORDER BY 2,1
  ) AS resultado
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY item;
```

Retornar lo siguiente:

```
A.1   = 1 veces
A.2.1 = 2 veces
A.3   = 6 veces
B.1   = 1 veces
```

Donde no solo no coinciden las cantidades de algunos items, sino que tambien se pasan por alto otros y no terminan figurando en el resultado final.

¿Alguna sugerencia de como corregir el SQL? 
Gracias desde ya.

Anexo la prueba del ejercicio aca: [consulta](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rciN8B2VjY5NsyiqjnCxLC/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta que estas planteando no te sirve, por que en definitiva no puedes contar más allá de la cantidad de filas de `combinaciones` y lo que en realidad ocurre es que cada fila puede a su vez tener más de un ítem. Sabiendo esto, lo que podemos hacer es "explotar" cada fila mediante [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html) y [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html) separando la cadena por los `;` y generar nuevas filas, luego solo restaría contar las apariciones de cada ítem:

```
SELECT s.token, count(1)
    FROM   combinaciones t, unnest(string_to_array(t.valor, ';')) s(token)
    group by s.token;
```

Salida:

```
+---+-------+-------+
| # | token | count |
+---+-------+-------+
| 1 | C     | 2     |
+---+-------+-------+
| 2 | A.3   | 6     |
+---+-------+-------+
| 3 | B.2   | 2     |
+---+-------+-------+
| 4 | D.1   | 2     |
+---+-------+-------+
| 5 | F     | 10    |
+---+-------+-------+
| 6 | B.1   | 4     |
+---+-------+-------+
| 7 | A.1   | 1     |
+---+-------+-------+
| 8 | A.2.1 | 2     |
+---+-------+-------+
```

#### Postgres < 8.4

Contamos con [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-string.html) para expandir cada fila según los ítems que contiene

```
select  s.token, count(1)
    from (select regexp_split_to_table(valor, ';') as token
            from combinaciones
       ) s
    group by s.token;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me sirvió parcialmente. Lo he probado en la version de desarrollo que utilizo que es un 9.1, pero no la puedo usar en producción debido a que el motor que usan en mi trabajo es *8.3!!!* y en dicha version la función *unnest()* no existe. Dudo que migren a una version mas nueva solo por una funcion. Me recomendarias alguna alternativa a la consulta que me diste anteriormente o alguna forma de generar una propia funcion *unnest()*. Gracias desde ya

Comment: @мαяςєlσ: `unnest()` aparece justa con la versión posterior 8.4, para 8.3 puedes usar `regexp_split_to_table verifica mi última edición.

Comment: Gracias Patricio!!!!  como me salvaste con la alternativa.

Comment: @мαяςєlσ, me alegro!

Answer (score 0):

Hola el problema lo tienes porque en el query interno, que busca las cadenas con el like, no funciona como puede parecer en un principio, ya que estás suponiendo que te hará todas las evaluaciones del case por cada fila, lo cual no es correcto. Si te fijas, ese query solo, te retorna 10 filas a pesar de que tienes separadas las condiciones para cada caso, esto es así porque el case al encontrar una condición que cumpla con lo esperado termina su ejecución. Para verlo con con tu caso tenemos que el valor:

```
fila 1 -> valor ('A.1;B.1;F'); entra en la condición: WHEN valor LIKE '%A.1%'   THEN 'A.1'
```

En éste punto ya la primera fila fue evaluada, y se encontró una condición en el case que la cumpla, por eso se pasa a la siguiente fila y por cada una sucede lo mismo. Vamos con la segunda fila:

```
fila 2 -> ('A.2.1;B.1;F'); entra en la condición: WHEN valor LIKE '%A.2.1%' THEN 'A.2.1'
```

Ya tenemos dos filas procesadas y nos hemos perdido los valores "B.1;F" de ambas filas.

Al final el resultado del query interno es:

```
A.1
A.2.1
A.2.1
A.3
A.3
A.3
A.3
A.3
A.3
B.1
```

Notarás que es el resultado de la primera condición encontrada en el case **para cada fila**.

Tienes que ver el procesamiento del case por fila, el lenguaje SQL trabaja por filas. También intenta trabajar por pedazos el query, primero el query interno y así sucesivamente para que veas éstos errores al momento.

Lo que debes hacer primero es separar los valores en filas, fíjate que tienes un ";" por cada valor eso te puede ayudar a separar; una vez tengas eso en filas puedes aplicar el mismo case que tienes y así debe darte el resultado esperado.

Esto:

```
('A.1;B.1;F');
```

Debe quedar como:

```
A.1
B.1
F
```

Saludos!